# JSON Deserialization of collections that contain null values

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I get the following JSON string:

`{"userIds":[null, "FA9C67A8-1C22-4393-A701-136C85BB0D6F"]}`

I would like to deserialize this to a set with one element (the UUID). My target class looks somewhat like this:

```
data class TestDto(
    val userIds: Set<UUID> = emptySet(),
    [...]
)
```

I am using Kotlin 1.5.21, Spring-Boot 2.4.4. The type of `userIds` does not allow null values in the set. However, when deserializing the JSON string the set consists of two values, the null value and the `UUID`. This leads to a `NullPointerException` later which I actually thought would be eliminated by setting the type to `Set<UUID>` instead of `Set<UUID?>`.

How can I sort of ignore/filter out any null values on deserialization if provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
@JsonSetter(contentNulls = Nulls.SKIP)
val userIds: Set<UUID> = emptySet(),
[...]
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves the problem.

I still wonder why this is necessary, as I use Kotlin

Comment: Kotlin will guarantee that there are no null values inside the Set, however, it will not guarantee that some code won't try to add null in the Set. Hence the NPE when some code tries.

Comment: I tried to add null to the set programmatically, it simply does not compile, which is expected. How can Jackson add null to the set and my code cannot? If null is not allowed in the set an error should occur or at least null should not be in the set, right?

Comment: Jackson is still Java code, not kotlin so it will compile there and will try to add null. It is correct that, if some java code tries to add null, it will throw the NPE since the Set will not allow it.