# NPE when passing null in request body when variable is not nullable

Tags: kotlin, null, nullpointerexception

I have a Kotlin app with a REST API. A `POST` endpoint accepts a request body, which is deserialized into this data class:

```kotlin
data class RequestBody(
    val ids: Ids? = null,
)

data class Ids(
    val include: List<String>? = null,
    val exclude: List<String>? = null
)
```

When calling this endpoint with:

```json
{
   "ids": {
        "include": [
            null
        ]
    },
}
```

I get an NPE when trying to serialize RequestBody using kotlinx JSON serializer:

```kotlin
val jsonSerializer = Json { encodeDefaults = true }

fun getData(
        ids: Ids
    ): Output {
    val inputJson = jsonSerializer.encodeToJsonElement(
        ids = Ids ?: Ids()
    )

    ...
}
```

Error message: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlinx.serialization.internal.StringSerializer.serialize`

For me it looks like the issue is during the deserialization of the request body, because, for example if I made `Ids` not nullable: `val ids: Ids`, and then tried to call the endpoint with `"ids": null`, then I'd get an expected error: `JSON parse error: Instantiation of [...] value failed for JSON property ids due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter ids which is a non-nullable type`.
So then why does it not throw this error when I pass null in the `include` list even though the `String` type is specified as not nullable?

Edit: In [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) it says that The only possible causes of an NPE in Kotlin are:

- An explicit call to `throw NullPointerException()`.
- Usage of the `!!` operator that is described below.
- Data inconsistency with regard to initialization, such as when:

  - An uninitialized `this` available in a constructor is passed and used somewhere (a "leaking `this`").
  - A superclass constructor calls an open member whose implementation in the derived class uses an uninitialized state.

This does not look like it fits in any of these?

Comment: There is a difference between passing a *list with a `null` element* and a *`null` value for the whole list*

Comment: You first say you *get* an NPE, and then you ask why you are *not* getting an NPE? You also show serialisation code but asks about deserialisation. Can you show a [mcve] and describe the problem, and what exactly you want to happen instead.

Comment: I ask why am I not getting a `HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error` not an NPE. I'm saying that the request body is getting deserialized into the data class (where the problem really lies), and then I get an NPE when serializing

Comment: re. your edit: There is another way to get `NullPointerException`s: Using Java reflection. For example, if you are *parsing* the JSON using some other non-Kotlin parser, it may very well fill your `List<String>?` with `null` elements.

Comment: What deserialization library are you using to parse the request body? If you can see that you have a `null` value in your list after deserialization, the whole thing about the serialization is just noise and can be reduced to just an element access causing the same NPE

Comment: It would be fairer to quote the _entire_ section of the documentation — which goes on to list several more causes of NPEs related to interoperability with non-Kotlin code (which is very likely what happened here).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are passing a `null` value into a List that doesn't accept `null`s. Try posting this instead:

```
{
   "ids": {
        "include": null
    },
}
```

Alternatively, update the list to accept `null` values:
`val include: List<String?>? = null`

Comment: > "you are passing a null value into a List that doesn't accept nulls".

That's the problem, it shouldn't accept nulls, but it does, and that causes an issue later in the code.
I'd expect this behaviour that I'm seeing if i had set: `val include: List<String?>? = null`, and either way I'd have to do a safe call because Kotlin would know that nulls are possible in that list. Now that I have explicitly specified that elements in the list cannot be null, I should be getting bad json format error as I specifed in the post.

Comment: @Hasherino I cannot reproduce that issue. `kotlinx.serialization` correctly accounts for nullability. When parsing the JSON you posted to the data class (without nullable elements), I get `Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 9: Expected string literal but 'null' literal was found `

Answer (score -2):

As Jorn said this most likely is caused by using a non-Kotlin parser to deserialize request data to data class. Used a `filterNotNull()` to work around the issue:

```kotlin
data class RequestBody(
    val ids: Ids? = null,
)

data class Ids(
    var include: List<String>? = null,
    var exclude: List<String>? = null
) {
    init {
        include = include?.filterNotNull()
        exclude = exclude?.filterNotNull()
    }
}
```

Edit: found an even better solution for this specific problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68633909/json-deserialization-of-collections-that-contain-null-values)

Comment: This just hides the problem under the rug, it doesn't fix the deserialization issue.